# TabBar application with multiple NSFetchedResultsController but only one UIManagedDocument

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uimanageddocument

I'm having some problems with the Core Data stuff, when used via a Managed Document.
I have a multiple tab application, and each tab must show different entities of a single database.
In order to initialize the Managed Document, I've created a helper class method that instantiates the Managed Document, creates it, opens it and adds all the data from a plist file. Next, it calls a block which is the parameter of this method. This way, I can call all this from one of the tab views, and pass through (by a block) the method that creates the fetchedResultsController.

```
+ (UIManagedDocument *)openDatabaseAndUseBlock:(completion_block_t)completionBlock;
```

I do it this way because I know the database opening takes a while, and if I set the FRC before it's opened, it won't work. So I call the block... in the block that's executed when the DB is opened.

My problem comes when switching between tabs. I call this helper method (with it's corresponding block) in the `viedDidLoad` of all the views, and I think this leads to data corruption, because all of the savings that are done.

There is any way I can call the helper method only once, on the first view, and then pass the context to all the other tabs, assuring that even if I switch the tab quickly at the beginning, it'll work?

**Or maybe I'm doing all the process wrong, and there's another way to get all this working? I'm totally new with Core Data.**

Thanks in advance!